# regex to search an array key

Tags: php, regex

I have an array called 'menu', which when put through print_r, currently outputs:

```
Array ( [4_00] => Array ( [0] => 1 ), [3_00] => Array ( [0] => 1 ), [7_00] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) )
```

I want to create an expression that will search this array for any keys beginning with '4_'. I have tried with this:

```
$matches = preg_grep( '/^4_/', $menu );
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Any help?

Much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain why? If you just need to match the first 2 characters how about `substr($key, 0, 2) === "4_"`?

Comment: Do you want just the keys returned?

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with a good old `foreach` loop and a string comparison? It gets the job done.

```
$results = array();
foreach ($menu as $key => $val) {
    if (strncmp($key, '4_', 2) === 0) {
        $results[] = array($key, $val);
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the function is poorly defined in the manual. The function [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) returns an array of the keys where the **value** of the array matches the regular expression.

**You would need a function [like this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php#95787) in order for you to work as expected**

```
function preg_grep_keys( $pattern, $input, $flags = 0 ) {
    $keys = preg_grep( $pattern, array_keys( $input ), $flags );
    $vals = array();
    foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
        $vals[$key] = $input[$key];
    }
    return $vals;
}
```

**And if you want to keep things really tight, you could even go [like this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php#111673)**

```
function preg_grep_keys($pattern, $input, $flags = 0) {
    return array_intersect_key($input, array_flip(preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($input), $flags)));
}
```

Comment: That was quite quick, is it some dummy account ?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering the same thing. The answer appeared about 45 seconds after the question was asked, not to mention the intervening edit.